# Initialize property of type immutable dictionary in Swift init()

Tags: swift, initialization, immutability, swift2, access-control

I would like to initialize an immutable dictionary by calculating its values in `init()`. I currently have:

```
class MyClass {
    var images: [String: UIImage]

    func init() {
        images = [:]
        for // ... loop over strings
            // ... calculate image
            images[string] = image
    }
}
```

Is there any way to define this property with `let` instead of `var` semantics. This would be convenient and seem appropriate as its content won't be changed after the object has been initialized. (If I just change this `var` into `let` I currently receive this error for the assignment inside the loop: "immutable value 'self.images' may not be assigned to".)

Comment: Just build the dictionary in a local variable first and then assign to the property ...

Comment: It might also be possible to use a functional expression to create the dictionary in one go but you would need to share more information about the calculation for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an additional variable in `init` and assign it once to `images`:

```
class MyClass {
    let images: [String: UIImage]

    func init() {
        var tempImages = [String: UIImage]()
        for // ... loop over strings
            // ... calculate image
            tempImages[string] = image

        // assign tempImages to images
        images = tempImages
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not require `self` during the dictionary computation, another option is to use an initialization block.

```
class MyClass {

    let images: [String: UIImage] = {
        var images = [String: UIImage]()
        images["foo"] = UIImage(named: "foo")
        images["bar"] = UIImage(named: "bar")
        return images
    }()

    // no explicit init required

}
```